# Xdebug and PhpStorm - Debugging not working

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm.

PHP Version 7.2.7 and Xdebug version 2.6.1

I have change the port to 9001 instead of 9000 (because it is listening to TCP)

Not it is listening to port. I have put breakpoint. But still it is not debugging.
[image]

Is there any setting I am still missing?

In Debugger: it is showing to 'Connected to localhost:65451' and project is demo.local (virtual host)

In Run -> Stop Listening to PHP Debug connections already have

Comment: Please provide screenshots. Based on your last line ... you are using JavaScript debugger  and not PHP one (initiated JavaScript debug session instead of PHP). Check this out: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: BTW -- *"(because it is listening to TCP)*" -- it will be listening on TCP even for port 9001... TCP is a protocol, not some software/service.

Comment: You are right @LazyOne. I have removed that. and Created PHP Script Debugger.

Comment: So .. you have resolved it now, right?

Comment: Yes @LazyOne.2 issues. I have multiple PHP installed. So need to check for correct php.ini and set PHP script debugger

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I am adding what worked for me here.

I was struggling with this thing from quite some time and I installed this extensions
Xdebug helper
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc/related
and it works for me!

Basically check if your phpstorm configurations are all right. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

Then I tried 3 plugins 
JetBrains Toolbox Extension (didn't worked)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-toolbox-extensi/offnedcbhjldheanlbojaefbfbllddna

JetBrains IDE Support(had some problem communicating with phpstorm or didn't worked )
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji

Xdebug helper (worked! yeeey )
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc/related

and that's it :D